# Zend: Modify Navigation Structure in a module

Tags: zend-framework, module

this is my current situation:

I have a xml to configure my general navigation structure.
In application/Bootstrap.php i have added the following function:

```
protected function _initViewHelpers()
{
    $this->bootstrap('layout');
    $oLayout = $this->getResource('layout');
    $oView = $oLayout->getView();
    $oNavContainerConfig = new Zend_Config_Xml(CONFIGPATH . 'navigation.xml', 'nav');
    $oNavigationContainer = new Zend_Navigation($oNavContainerConfig);

    $aCurrentRole = $this->_auth->getStorage()->read();
    @$oView->navigation($oNavigationContainer)->setAcl($this->_acl)->setRole($aCurrentRole->role);
}
```

and this is my current plugin:

```
class Discount_Plugin_Module extends Zend_Controller_Plugin_Abstract
{
    public function routeShutdown(Zend_Controller_Request_Abstract $oRequest)
    {
        // init all module view controller stuff
    }
}
```

I want to modify my navigation in runtime. I want to add module specific navigation items.

I have no idea how the navigation structure can be mofify from the module.

Hope you can help me.

Max

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In order to accomplish the same thing, I use and object that I created to build the menu.  You can find the code that I use here: http://pastebin.com/FzChbVeV .  I also use a helper to check if the user is allowed to see the link.  You can remove the lines 102 to 109 and edit the line 111 if you don't want to use it.

After that, in the bootstrap.php of my module, I add the following code to add menu items:

```
    $menu = ZARD_Object_Module_Multimodmenu::getInstance();

    $menu->id = 'submenuid';
    $menu->label = 'Submenu';
    $menu->module = 'default';
    $menu->controller = 'index';
    $menu->action = 'index';
    $menu->addItem();

    $menu->id = 'amenuitem';
    $menu->label = 'Menu Item';
    $menu->module = 'modulename';
    $menu->controller = 'controllername';
    $menu->action = 'actionname';
    $menu->parent = 'submenuid';
    $menu->addItem();
```

After that, I load the menu in my layout:

```
    $menu = ZARD_Object_Module_Multimodmenu::getInstance();
    echo $menu->getMenu();
```

Comment: Thank for this. Currently i`m using an xml for my nav structure and combine it with my ACL. So i can ensure, that each user gets the navigation he is allowed to.

Any idea how to extend your class with die ACL and the xml structure?

Comment: Just a suggestion but I won't go through the whole code here...  You could use the Zend_Registry to hold your Zend_Navigation() object.  Somewhere in your application's bootstrap: Zend_Registry->set('navMenu', new Zend_Navigation()); and then, anywhere in the code, you could load your menu with $menu=Zend_Registry->get('navMenu'); and add pages or edit it the way you like, $menu->addPage('page'); for example.  They key is to load you module specific options in your module's bootstrap.